# How do you secure your ASP.Net Web API without catering for third parties?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have done a lot of reading about how to secure your ASP.Net Web API. It has been quite confusing and their documentation isn't always very clear. This may be a duplicate question but my searches on SO haven't found anything 100%.

I get that if you want to give a third party access to your Web API then you need something like OAuth. I have read a ton of examples with OAuth and after reading I am convinced that this is not the way for me to go. I don't want to give anyone else access to the API.

This is my scenario. I have used ASP.Net MVC 4 and Web API for the backend. I have used Angularjs and created a SPA web app in the front end. Users log in for themselves and can use the system. I will never want to allow a third party to develop anything against our API. However the Web API is attractive because it does away with the needs for a Session. This means we can scale things better if the web server ever gets too busy.

I have read about HTTP basic authentication but that would mean that I would have to valid every request. If the user information is in the DB or behind some network service then it is extra IO for every call which seems bad. I prefer the idea that, once you have a token, you are good to go and the server can just do some maths on every call.

The ASP.Net MVC Angularjs template uses normal forms auth (cookies) and HTTP anti forgery tokens. I would be happy to use this approach BUT wasn't there a movement recently to get rid off cookies in the browser? Or was it to have cookies disabled by default and users had to turn them on? (I.e. opt in rather than opt out).

I like the idea of OAuth because tokens could contain claims like what role the user was in. I am not sure how forms Auth would include role information unless it gets stored in the cookie too.

**UPDATED: (based on vote to close because it wasn't clear what I was asking)**

What is the easiest way to authenticate AJAX requests coming in to Web API and to do authorization on roles? Do not need to provide access to third parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

> BUT wasn't there a movement recently to get rid off cookies in the
>   browser? Or was it to have cookies disabled by default and users had
>   to turn them on? (I.e. opt in rather than opt out)

As far as I'm aware, only persistent cookies (or permanent cookies) require opt in.  So, in your case, it doesn't seem like you would have to worry about using cookies.

---

That aside, I'm still not sure what the problem is.  You seem to have decided that OAuth is not the correct tool and that basic authentication is a bit awkward.

However, you also express a solution that seems to meet your requirements.  Namely, to have a token that is sent back after authentication that can be sent in with each request and some math applied to verify its authenticity.  This can be accomplished by using some sort of private random information on the server that can be encrypted or hashed when created and then verified on each request.  You can stick this in a custom HTTP header.

I think the problem that you'll run into is still session.  In essence, creating a server session is about tracking the time period that the user is authorized to use the service.  So, there is a bit of state there.

First, you have the random created information (that the token represents/contains) that allows you to verify.  You need some way to verify that the value in the HTTP request header (token) came from you.  However, you also (probably) need some way to manage expiry of the authorized time period.  As long as some upper limit on how long somebody can be authorized.

So, the way I see it, you either have to store this information on the server or inside the token itself.  Otherwise, it sounds like you are on the right track.

Comment: I was looking at Simple Web Token where the expiry is encoded in the token. That seems to be a good fit for us. Thanks for your feedback. I am feeling more comfortable now that I am attempting the right sort of thing. Would you recommend that I use the HTTP authorization header and then use my own custom scheme? Would that be browser inter-operable?

Comment: Any HTTP header is browser inter-operable.  You are using HTTP directly so adding a header should be fine.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that you are using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

i did not see any possibility a software can help you to secure your online service, but know more deeper about how http works may help you.
to your questions,
4. no, they are commonly used in lots of sites
but yes, the cookie / form can be hacked also. in fact entire http request can be hacked, since http is pretty simple as a text based protocol. each field can be abused by the users or gateways. the reason some people thought cookie / form are dangerous is because, your server may use the input to modify / insert / delete your data. but this is just the expected functionality of these technologies. to avoid it, you need to carefully parse the request fields, do not try to directly paste the value to sql command, you need to verify if it is well-formatted first, etc.
6. you can check user-agent to detect whether the request is coming from a tablet, but the assumption of 'tablets are't always able to use cookies' is not correct.